# Sony Spresense Deep Sleepでの電力

Tags: spresense

Sony Spresense単体でDeep Sleepモードに入れた場合（SDKでもArduino IDE環境下でも）、
数十uA(80uA前後）となります。（CN1から給電、電源LED消費分を除く）

ドキュメント上は数uA程度と記載があるのですが、元のコンフィグレーション等により電力が大きいのでしょうか。
できるだけ低消費電力の温度ロガーを作ろうとしています。センサで使用するのはI2Cです。
可能な限り低消費電力化したいのですが、可能な手段をご教示ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

同じこと画策・検討しているひとはいるもんですね。
可能な限りの低消費電力化は私も実験済みなので共有しておきます。

これ製品保証の対象外になるのは当然ですが...
ボードが壊れたり、その他の損失や損害があっても私は一切の責任を負いかねます、
と免責事項は書いておきます。あくまで参考程度に。

やり方は、回路図と部品配置図を眺めながら、
バッテリー直で電流を喰っている部品を地道に外していきました。
https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/hardware-documentation

結果的にDeep Sleepで数uAレベルまで落とすことができてます。

電源供給回りで、

① POWER LED の R21 を外す

→ 給電状態が見た目で判断つかなくなってしまいますが、これだけで数100uA分は削減できます

② 5V_VBUSからのダイオード D1 を外す
③ Battery -> ACP_PWR へのロードスイッチ IC8(TCK112G) を外してA2,A1を直結(ショート)する

USBからの電源供給はカットして常にCN1から給電する
Batteryへの逆流防止機能がなくなってしまうので、5V_MAINから給電しないこと

→ ここまでやってDeep Sleepモードの消費電流が 20-25uA ぐらいになります。

RESET スイッチ回りで、

④ XRS_PWON の PD抵抗 R28 を外す
⑤ UART_DTR の C76 を外す

USB-UARTでシリアルモニタを接続する時に基板リセットがかからなくなります。
プログラムを書き込む際は、flash_writer を実行した直後にRESETスイッチを押せば問題無く書き込みできます(flash_writerが動かなくなったのでちょっと焦りましたが回避できました)

→ Deep Sleepモードで 5-6 uA ぐらい

Spresenseにバッテリーを付けて超低消費電力ロガーを動かしています。
バッテリー駆動時間が半端ないです。

Comment: ご返事が遅くなり、大変申し訳ございません。大変参考になりました。宇宙での用途を検討しております。