# SPRESENSEの消費電力を知りたい

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEのメインボードに加えて、HDRカメラ、LTE拡張ボードの購入を検討しているのですが、これらを使って下記条件でAzureのIoTHubに画像を伝送したいと考えております。
その際にかかる消費電力をざっくりで結構ですので、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。

**条件**

- 画像サイズ：QVGA
- 画像撮影・伝送頻度：10分に1回
- AzureIoTHubにアップロード
  https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/lte_azureiot
- 上記以外はスリーブ状態とする

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。[消費電力 - バッテリレス超簡易監視カメラ by HomeMadeGarbage](https://elchika.com/article/0b74da45-51a3-47ab-9e95-3142f88ef6cd/#h_%E6%B6%88%E8%B2%BB%E9%9B%BB%E5%8A%9B), [SPRESENSEの消費電力を可視化して解析](https://www.aps-web.jp/academy/amp/10632/), [SPRESENSE メインボードとカメラの消費電力を測定してみた](https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2020-02-21), [Spresense LTE拡張ボードで最大消費電力が 1.2A になるのはどのような場面で発生する？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88470/26370), [Sony Spresense Deep Sleepでの電力](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/55366/26370)

Comment: @kunif さま
ご回答ありがとうございます。
上記を参考に、消費電力を算出してみたいと思います。

Comment: もし解決したのであればご自身で自己回答の形で投稿してみてください。(タイトルに 解決済み と付けるのは良くない編集です)